# realizar suma de una columna y mostrarla por id de usuario en LARAVEL X8

Tags: laravel-8

tengo un problema estoy muy nuevo en laravel, tengo 1 columna en mysql la cual quiero sumar y mostrársela al usuario

quiero sumar la columna de monto pero no me sale la consulta esto es lo que tengo en el controlador
para hacerlo con un @foreach

```
public function index()
{
 //ver por ID DE USUARIO 
$Gastos = Gastos::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->latest()->get();
$Gastos = Gastos::latest()->get();
    return view('paginas.inicio', compact('Gastos'));
}
```

columna se llama monto

monto

15.000
20.000

coloco esta $monto= Gastos::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->sum('monto') en el controlador y en la vista

```
 @foreach($monto as $subarray)
      <th> {{$subarray['monto']}}</th>
   @endforeach
```

pero me sale el siguiente error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Intentastes `Gastos::sum('monto')`?

Comment: siii efectivamente esa fue la primera que intente pero no funciono

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/417622/edit) tu pregunta y agregar el porque no te funciono, si salio un error, etc

Comment: me sale este error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Por eso te digo que edites tu pregunta y agreges el codigo que pusistes

Comment: gracias ya la puse

Comment: Estas haciendo esto? `foreach(Gastos::sum('monto') as $monto)`? Para hacer el `sum` no es necesario un `foreach`, [sum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum) ahi esta su documentacion

Comment: @foreach($monto as $subarray)
      <th> {{$subarray['monto']}}</th>
   @endforeach

Comment: recibo este error Trying to access array offset on value of type float tengo esto en la vista  <th>{{ number_format($monto['monto']) }}</th>

Comment: sii ya funciono muchas gracias <th>{{ number_format($monto) }}</th>

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta si te sirivio

Answer (score 1):

Para no complicar mas las cosas esta seria la solucion:

```
public function index()
{
 //ver por ID DE USUARIO 
$monto= Gastos::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->sum('monto')
    return view('paginas.inicio', compact('monto'));
}
```

La variable `monto` ya te devuelve la suma de toda esa columna y no es necesario hacer el `foreach`, lee la documentacion para saber mas detalles [sum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum)